# error in accessing mysql OUT variable in php

Tags: php, mysql

My code attempts to verify the user, by checking if that user is in the database. vv_check will be set to 1 if the user exists, else 0.

```
$sql = "CALL VerifyUsers('$temp','$te',@vv_check)";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $rs2 = mysqli_query($con,"select @vv_check as ch");
    echo $rs2->ch
```

this is my procedure

```
         DELIMITER $$
         CREATE PROCEDURE VerifyUsers
 (
IN vv_email varchar(20),
IN vv_psswd varchar(10),
OUT vv_check int
)
BEGIN
DECLARE v_id int;
DECLARE v_uname varchar(20);
DECLARE v_name varchar(20);
DECLARE v_email varchar(35);
DECLARE v_psswd varchar(10);
DECLARE rec int;
DECLARE use_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_email = vv_email and users_psswd=vv_psswd ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
FOR NOT FOUND SET rec = 1;
SET vv_check = 0;
OPEN use_cursor;
use_loop : LOOP
IF rec=1 THEN
LEAVE use_loop;
END IF;
FETCH use_cursor into v_id,v_uname,v_name,v_email,v_psswd ;
IF v_email=vv_email and v_psswd=vv_psswd THEN
SET vv_check = 1;
END IF;
END LOOP use_loop;
CLOSE use_cursor;
END $$
DELIMITER  ;;
```

I get this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\pack\login.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a line for this to work because mysql return resource for the query executed which needed to be fetched to array.

```
$rs2 = mysqli_query($con,"select @vv_check as ch");
$rs2_result = mysqli_fetch_array($rs2,MYSQLI_ASSOC); //add this line...
print_r($rs2_result);
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out mysqli syntax.

mysql_query gives you the result resource. you should use mysql_fetch_object or mysql_fetch_row

```
$rs2 = mysqli_query($con,"select @vv_check as ch");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($rs2)) {
echo $row->ch;
}
mysqli_free_result($rs2);
```

Thanks

Comment: Why you combining mysqli with mysql?